# Can you access a swift subscript as a closure?

Tags: swift, syntax, closures

Given the following class in swift:

```
public class Foo {
    public init () { }
    public subscript (index: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return index
        }
    }

    public func intIdentity (val: Int) -> Int {
        get {
            return val
        }
    }
}
```

Clearly I can access `intIdentity` as a closure by using something like this:

```
let foo = Foo()
let clos = foo.intIdentity
print (clos (7)) // -> 7
```

Also, I know I can wrap it in a closure like this:

```
let foo = Foo()
let clos = { (x:Int)->Int in return foo[x] }
print (clos (42)) // -> 42
```

How can I access the subscript directly as a closure? Is it impossible because even though the subscript is syntactic sugar on top of one or two functions, they are implicit and can't be accessed explicitly?